# Logging user access in alfresco log file

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I added the following line in alfresco log 4j file.

```
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.util.log.NDC=debug
log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %x %-5p [%c] %m%n
```

But still the log file is not logging the user login access.

How to make alfresco share to log the user login details.

Answer (score 2):

Share does not support NDC logging of the username out of the box - only the repository does. However, it can easily be implemented with a filter:

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            String userId = AuthenticationUtil.getUserId((HttpServletRequest) request);
            NDC.remove();
            if (userId != null) {
                    NDC.push("User:" + userId);
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```